# Set insets on UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uiedgeinsets

I'm trying to set some insets in a UILabel. It worked perfectly, but now  `UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect` has been replaced with `CGRect.inset(by:)` and I can't find out how to solve this.

When I'm trying to use `CGRect.inset(by:)` with my insets, then I'm getting the message that `UIEdgeInsets` isn't convertible to `CGRect`.

#### My code

```
class TagLabel: UILabel {
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let inset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -2, left: 2, bottom: -2, right: 2)
        
        super.drawText(in: CGRect.insetBy(inset))
//        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, inset)) // Old code
    }

}
```

Anyone knows how to set the insets to the UILabel?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Imho you also have to update the `intrinsicContentSize`:

```
class InsetLabel: UILabel {

    let inset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -2, left: 2, bottom: -2, right: 2)

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: inset))
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var intrinsicContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        intrinsicContentSize.width += inset.left + inset.right
        intrinsicContentSize.height += inset.top + inset.bottom
        return intrinsicContentSize
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the better answer. If you're finicky enough to be messing with the insets, you're also going to want sizeToFit(). The intrinsicContentSize method above lets that work correctly.

Answer (score 15):

Please update your code as below

```
 class TagLabel: UILabel {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let inset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -2, left: 2, bottom: -2, right: 2)
        super.drawText(in: rect.insetBy(inset))
    }
}
```

Comment: I used `rect.inset(inset)` -> which takes UIEdgeInsets

Comment: @JacobAhlberg, sorry, there are 2 methods :)

Comment: In Swift 4 (Apr. 11, 2020), I had to use: `super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))` instead of: `super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))`

Answer (score 4):

> this code differs from the accepted answer because the accepted answer uses insetBy(inset) and this answer uses inset(by: inset). When I added this answer in iOS 10.1 and Swift 4.2.1 autocomplete DID NOT give you rect.inset(by: ) and I had to manually type it in. Maybe it does in Swift 5, I'm not sure

For iOS `10.1` and `Swift 4.2.1` use `rect.inset(by:`)

this:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let inset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -2, left: 2, bottom: -2, right: 2)

    super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: inset))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**
replace method drawText(...) with draw(...)

```
extension UILabel {

open override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let inset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -2, left: 2, bottom: -2, right: 2)
    super.draw(rect.inset(by: inset))
    
}}
```